# Filter Column with Formula and Display in other Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of names in column G and a assigned reviewer in column A. I'd like to have a list of all names in column G assigned to a specific name from column A. I then move that list to another spreadsheet.

I got this started with `=if('Example Confirmations All'!A2=$B$1, 'Example Confirmations All'!E2, "")`, but then I end up with a blank cell for every entry that doesn't match `B1`.

I'd love to either (a) filter the formula above so there is no blank cells between output or (b) find a smarter formula to pull data into the spreadsheet in the first place.

Here's some example output:

> > `Reviewer la      la  la  Nominee la  ...`
> >     `George   data    data    data    Jill    data    ...`

(sorry for the terrible formatting..)

EDIT

I have the entire list of nominees showing up with `=filter('Example Confirmations All'!E2:E50,'Example Confirmations All'!A2=$B$1)` with B1 being a static definition of who the reviewer is for this page... seems closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in your edit is close, you just need to reference the entire range in the condition:

`=FILTER('Example Confirmations All'!E2:E50;'Example Confirmations All'!A2:A50=$B$1)`

or as an alternative:

`=QUERY('Example Confirmations All'!A2:E50;"Select E where A='"&$B$1&"'";0)`

Comment: See, I can read the FILTER output.. but could you walk me through the QUERY? I'll give it a go right now to see if it works here. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh, I see, basically scoops up a matrix then `if` statements it. Anything to keep in mind with that `;0` at the end? Is that the `headers` parameter?

Comment: Yes that third argument specifies the number of header rows in the source data. If it is omitted, Sheets will "guess" how many header rows you have. Occasionally it guesses wrong (giving unexpected results), so I think it's good practice to include it.